# Inserting html using the RazorEngine to be rendered as HTML is populated template

Tags: c#, html, razor

I'm having a problem rendering html in a HTML template. I am currently using the razorEngine to populate templates we then use in emails. The information I am having issues with rendering is a url. Because of a client requirement we cannot have clickable links inside of emails so instead I have to have the url as a plain string, the problem with email clients is that they will render a url string as a link regardless of if you define it as a link or not. To circumvent this I have added a couple zero space images throughout the link to break it.

This is the code populating the template:

```
Engine.Razor.Compile(content, "template");
Engine.Razor.Run("template", null, data)
```

data passed in is a JObject:

```
{
    "Code": "235466",
    "FirstName": "First",
    "LastName": "Last",
    "URL": "<p>http<img src=\"\" width=\"0\" height=\"0\">s:<img src=\"\" width=\"0\" height=\"0\">//test.<img src=\"\" width=\"0\" height=\"0\">test.<img src=\"\" width=\"0\" height=\"0\">com/account/forgotpassword/</p>"
}
```

Tags in the template match with the template typically like this:

- @Model.FirstName
- @Model.LastName
- @Model.LastName

Apart from the url which i'm trying to render as html:

- @Raw(Model.URL)

The following error gets thrown when attempting the enter the values:

*Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The best overloaded method match for 'RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateBase.Raw(string)' has some invalid arguments*

If I was to place the URL directly into the Raw() it works correctly:

```
@Raw("<p>http<img src="" width="0" height="0">s:<img src="" width="0" height="0">//test.<img src="" width="0" height="0">test.<img src="" width="0" height="0">com/account/forgotpassword/</p>")
```

Can anyone see what I am missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Model.URL` isn't a string. It's probably a `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue`. You'll need to convert it to a string first using:

```
@Raw(Model.URL.ToString())
```

Just be careful and ensure Model.URL isn't null.

Answer (score 0):

The call to @Raw() expects an IEncodedString not a literal.

[For @Raw, see here](https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/references/razorengine-templating-templatebase.html)

[For IEncodedString, see here](https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/references/razorengine-text-iencodedstring.html)